# How do I get colorized query output and shell in MongoDB?

Tags: json, shell, mongodb, colors

It would be really nice to be able to view the output with colorized keys and values.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Check out this shell extension I made called Mongo-Hacker that has various enhancements:

- [Mongo Hacker Website](http://tylerbrock.github.com/mongo-hacker/)
- [Code (GitHub)](http://www.github.com/tylerbrock/mongo-hacker/)

[image: Colorized MongoDB Shell]

Comment: The third line of the installation instructions on the website didn't work for me. `ln -sf mongo_hacker.js ~/.mongorc.js` would only work if `mongo_hacker.js` is in `~/` so the instructions should be something like `ln -sf <mongo-hacker-dir>/mongo_hacker.js ~/.mongorc.js` instead (as it is on github).

Comment: @Tyler
Auto multi update (works just like update in SQL)  any way to disable this?

Comment: @JohnnyHK you have to cd into the cloned directory, did you skip that step?

Comment: @RaxitSheth sure: `setAutoMulti(false)`

Comment: @TylerBrock Yes, I did cd into the cloned directory.  On Ubuntu, at least, just the `mongo_hacker.js` target is saved into the symlink, without the path to the current working directory.

Comment: @RaxitSheth in the latest version, update works normally (as the non-modified shell) if called on a collection. If you chain it on a query, `db.coll.find().update()`, it does a multi which you can constrain using limit `db.coll.find().limit(n).update()`.

Comment: symlinking in centos did not work for me, mongo was not using the js file. copying solved the problem.